# Tip calculator crashes when calculate button clicked

Tags: java, android

When Calculate button clicked the app crashes.

```
package thumbplay.tip;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class tip extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tip);
         final EditText billamt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tbill);
        final EditText tip_percent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tpercent);
        final TextView totalbill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gt);
         Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                         public void onClick(View v) {

                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have netered this ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                             final double billamt1;
                                             final double tip_percent1;
                                             final double totalbill1;
                                             final double tip_cal;


                                             billamt1 = Double.parseDouble(billamt.toString());
                                             tip_percent1 = Double.parseDouble(tip_percent.toString());
                                             tip_cal= (billamt1 * tip_percent1)/100; //When Calculate button clicked the app crashes 
                                            totalbill.setText(Double.toString(tip_cal));
                                         }
                                     }
        );
    }
}
```

When Calculate button clicked the app crashes

Comment: can you post error log?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the texts from `EditText` first .

```
billamt1=Double.parseDouble(billamt.gettext().toString());
tip_percent1=Double.parseDouble(tip_percent.gettext().toString());
```

The app is crashing due to the null pointer exception because you are not getting any data from the `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

error is in this line

```
billamt1 = Double.parseDouble(billamt.toString());
```

Here `billamt` is your `EditText` and if you want value of it, you should use `billamt.getText().toString()`

same thing goes for

```
tip_percent1 = Double.parseDouble(tip_percent.toString());
```

`tip_percent` is also `EditText` so use `tip_percent.getText().toString()`